# moving an object on mapbox map unity with device gps

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gps, mapbox

object stays in the same position location provider is not working i dont know why
i dont knoiw what else to try if someone can help! i took a script i found about find device gps cords and then i added transform.position but its a failure

```
    IEnumerator GetLocation()
    {
        if (!Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.FineLocation))
        {
            Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.FineLocation);
            Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.CoarseLocation);
        }
        // First, check if user has location service enabled
        if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);

        // Start service before querying location
        Input.location.Start();

        // Wait until service initializes
        int maxWait = 10;
        while (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            maxWait--;
        }

        // Service didn't initialize in 20 seconds
        if (maxWait < 1)
        {
           
            yield break;
        }

        // Connection has failed
        if (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed)
        {
            
            yield break;
        }
        else
        {

           float latitude = Input.location.lastData.latitude;
           float longitude = Input.location.lastData.longitude;

            // Set the position of a GameObject using the GPS values

           transform.position = new Vector3(longitude , 0, latitude);

        }

        // Stop service if there is no need to query location updates continuously
        isUpdating = !isUpdating;
        Input.location.Stop();
        
    }
}
```

Comment: it starts like this public class usinggps : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float x, z;
    public bool isUpdating;
    private void Update()
    {
        if (!isUpdating)
        {
            StartCoroutine(GetLocation());
            isUpdating = !isUpdating;
            
        }
    }